# Is Spring bean just a shared object

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand purpose of Spring-created beans. Are they just global shared object (such that they are declared like

```
@Component 
public class MySpringBean{},
```

and later this object is used anywhere like inside some class

```
public class MyClass {
@Autowired 
MySpringBean mySpringBean;
}
```

)?
Can their internal creation/implementation assumed like this? -

```
public class MyApp {
MySpringBean mySpringBean;
}
```

and used in MyClass like -

```
public class MyClass {
MySpringBean mySpringBean = MyApp.mySpringBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the object valid for only that class hierarchy.  In your case Spring just create an object for mySpringBean and will keep it available for MyClass. Internally its more like

```
MySpringBean mySpringBean = new MySpringBean()
```

But actually
all Spring beans are managed - they "live" inside a container, called "application context".
Autowiring happens by placing an instance of one bean into the desired field in an instance of another bean. Both classes should be beans, i.e. they should be defined to live in the application context.

so in your case both mySpringBean  and an instance of MyClass will be in application context.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your question, I believe you should know about how beans are managed by Spring (or how Spring manages the life cycle of beans from initialization to destroy). **But also note that you don't have to go into too much of details (wells, it's a framework that's is providing you).** Yes, it's definitely true to init involves using `new` operator. These objects live inside the Container and Spring wires them whenever it's called for. Since beans are managed by Spring, you can implement **callback** methods too.